# Creating a text file from PL/SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, plsqldeveloper

Can someone explain how to create a text file and save to my C drive from a select query? Anytime I run the query I would like the query to replace the old text file with the new query data.

Comment: From the server or a separate client machine? From which client? How will you run the query? Is PL/SQL required?

Comment: I'm not sure! I'm using PL/SQL to extract data from an Oracle environment on my desktop, connecting directly to a server. My aplogies, I'm a beginner.

Comment: You can't use PL/SQL to write to the client that connects to the server. A stored procedure runs **on the server** and only has access to the file system of the server. A stored procedure can never access the file system of the client computer calling the procedure

Comment: Are you really using PL/SQL (the language), or are you perhaps using the PL/SQL Developer client? It sounds more likely that you're doing a plain SQL query, rather than executing a PL/SQL block.

Comment: Yes, I'm just using PL/SQL the client.

Comment: There is no such thing as "PL/SQL the client". PL/SQL is a _programming language_ (for stored procedures) and the code runs on the **server** not "the client".

Comment: They are different things and the distinction is important, especially when asking for help - [PL/SQL is a language](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/overview.htm#LNPLS001). while [PL/SQL Developer is a client](https://www.allroundautomations.com/plsqldev.html). I believe that supports `spool` but I don't use it much so not sure about the details.

Comment: I see, thanks for the education. Yes, I'm using PL/SQL Developer.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to follow the steps :

1. save this in file named get_data.sql

   ```
   SET HEADING OFF
   SET FEEDBACK OFF
   SET TERM OFF
   SET LONG 100000
   SPOOL Dept_100.txt
   select 'EmployeeName  : '||Emp_id from Employee where Deptno = 100;
   SPOOL OFF
   ```
2. on CMD, Go to the folder where the script is.
3. connect using sqlplus through command prompt.
4. Run the script

   ```
   SQL>@spool.sql
   ```
5. `spool.sql` contains select statement which will select employeename of all     employees who work for Dept :100(Just for example).
6. running spool.sql will create a file  "Dept_100.txt" containing employeenames.